# How do I create a regular expression that doesn't match for certain variations of a string?

Tags: regex

I wish to build a regular expression that does not match the first example below, the next 2 lines are examples of acceptable matches.

```
Distribute( SystemEvent, device, NULL)
Distribute(123)
Distribute( 123)
```

In words I want to match Distribute, followed by (, followed by an optional space, followed by anything that does not start with a capital S.

The expression below matches the first line though I thought the [^S] would stop that.

```
Distribute\( ?[^S]s
```

Comment: What programming language are you working in?

Comment: C in Renesas HEW IDE

Answer (score 4):

```
Distribute\( ?[^ S]
```

The first line is matched because `?` maches with length zero, and then space goes under `[^S]`. So add space to the neg-group.

Comment: I thought the ? would match zero or one occurrence of the previous 'blank' character. The space preceding the 'S' is optional. BTW, the trailing 's' was a typo.

Comment: The bracket needs to be escaped.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness thanks.

Comment: @user2579721 Yes, it tried to match space to space, then failed at S,  so it got back and succeeded on the other way.

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix it is this (considering It is PCRE):

`Distribute\( ?+[^S]`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jHbB12/1/)**

By adding a `+` after `?` you modify it to make it possesive (you match as much as you can and you don't go back)

On your regexp, since the `?` was not posessive, it matched 0 times and then matched a non 'S' (a space)

Comment: Downvoter, please explain :)

Comment: It's incorrect, you want to use a lookahead here.

Comment: Why incorrect? Could you please elaborate where does it fail?

Comment: why would he want to use a lookahead?

Comment: I removed the downvote but I think OP wants to match `Distribute` only.

Comment: In OP's words, `I want to match Distribute, followed by (, followed by an optional space, followed by anything that does not start with a capital S`

Comment: Yes, you can also read that he wants to match Distribute when followed by etc etc. It wouldn't be the first time that OP does not write his question properly.

Comment: And using the lookahead is less efficient, compare 50 steps vs the 41 without it, for a string length only 13

Comment: Also logically speaking, why would someone want to match `Distribute( 1` ?

Comment: I do not think you understood my comment.

Comment: for a simple boolean match true/false

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure of your intentions, but if you are relying on human input, you should probably allow for more than one space

`Distribute\( *+[^S]`

Comment: Good point about spaces, but in this case it is program debug output and all outputs start with zero or one spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Distribute\( ?(?=\S)(?=[^S])[^)]+\)
```

This matches `Distribute(` followed by a possible space then it uses a positive lookahead to check that the next character is not a white space character and then it checks that that character is also not an `S` Then it checks for one or more not `)` characters followed by a `)`